# How to use Mapper.Map with function?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I know how to use map without function. This is input:

```
Id: 1
Name: Something
Color: -9690922
```

And expected output:

```
Id: 1
Name: Something
Color: (29, 3, 201, 1)
```

I have a function that  converts this color from number, but how to use it within the mapper?

Answer (score 2):

You should use MapFrom option while creating map. 
So if your function to convert colour from number is CreateCol() use something like:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<EFAddress, Address>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Color, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
  CreateCol(src.Color)));
```

Comment: In my case it looks like this: `Projects = Mapper.Map<Project[], List<ProjectDTO>>(res.ToArray())`